# Try and except overwrites for loop user input

Tags: python

I've been trying to put in a try and except into a for loop. It works how it should but the for loop only saves the last racer races not all racer's races.
I believe this due to the try and except.

```
for name in [runner1, runner2, runner3]:
    while True:
        try:
            race1 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 1:"))
            race2 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 2:"))
            race3 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 3:"))
            race4 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 4:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a integer")
            continue
        break
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `try - except` block,  for each iteration `race1 - race4` are getting updated.

Comment: I find this as not very good design. Imagine user can enter race1 and race2 correctly and then race4 wrong. This means that user has to enter values 1 a 2 again in the next iteration.

Comment: The problem is that you reassign `race1..4` in every iteration of the `for` loop, so naturally only the variables set in the last interation are kept.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a brief redesign would help here.

```
for name in [runner1, runner2, runner3]:
    race = dict()
    for r in range(4):
        while True:
            try:
                race[r] = int(input("{0}: Enter runner placing for race {1}:".format(name, r+1)))
            except ValueError:
                print("Enter a integer")
                continue
            break
    # do something for this particular value of race[]
    # before continuing on to the next runner
```

If you can't handle the inputs inside the loop, then save them in a dictionary.

```
runners = {x: None for x in [runner1, runner2, runner3]}
for name in runners.keys():
    race = dict()
    for r in range(4):
        while True:
            try:
                race[r] = int(input("{0}: Enter runner placing for race {1}:".format(name, r+1)))
            except ValueError:
                print("Enter a integer")
                continue
            break
    runners[name] = race
```

At this point, `runners[runner1][2]` has the value for `runner1` for race 3 (remember Python array indices are zero-based).

Comment: You define an empty list `race = []` and try to assign values with `race[r] = [...]`. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seams to be, that your overwrite the previous input every round through the loop. there is only one variable `race1` which is then assigned a new value in the next iteration. A better design would be to have a dictionary from runners to race-positions like so:

```
runners = {runner1:[], runner2:[], runner3:[]}
for runner in runners:
    while True:
        try:
            race1 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 1:"))
            race2 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 2:"))
            race3 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 3:"))
            race4 = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race 4:"))
            runners[runner] = [race1, race2, race3, race4]
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a integer")
            continue
        break
```

this would give you a dictionary with runners as keys and a list of their placings as values.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to more better design. Also, store race1-4 values in some sort of collection before loosing them in other loop

```
for name in [runner1, runner2, runner3]:
    race1 = inputForRace(1)
    race2 = inputForRace(2)
    race3 = inputForRace(3)
    race4 = inputForRace(4)


def inputForRace(raceOrder):
   shouldContinue = True
   race = 0
   while shouldContinue:
      try:
         race = int(input(name + ": Enter runner placing for race {0}:".format(raceOrder)))
         shouldContinue = False
      catch ValueError:
        print("Enter integer")
        shouldContinue = True
   return race
```